# Calculate permanent of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, permanent

How can I find a permanent of a square matrix (for a general dimension nxn) in R? In particular, I'm trying to find a pdf of order statistics for independent but not identically distributed populations, which includes calculating a permanent of a matrix whose elements are pdfs and cdfs of the original populations

thanks

Comment: For those of us with insufficient background, would you like to explain what a "permanent" is. (I'm wondering if you meant to write "determinant", in whcihc case you would probably want to delete this question and just do a search using the standard `??`-facilities in R.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent

Comment: It's basically like determinant but each term comes in with a + sign

Comment: whether @BondedDust's brute-force solution is adequate, or whether you will need to implement Ryser's algorithm in R, or wrap a C implementation (and whether you need to modify the C implementation pointed to below) will depend on how big your matrices are and whether they are integer or floating-point ...

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr** this is a non-trivial computational problem that doesn't seem to have been implemented in R, and is computationally hard enough that a compiled solution may be necessary. Your best bet would be to write R code wrapping [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21282/Compute-Permanent-of-a-Matrix-with-Ryser-s-Algorit) open source C implementation.

Based on [the relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent), "Ryser" looks like a good search term for finding implementations of this computation. `library("sos"); findFn("Ryser")` finds only the help for [Spearman's rank correlation](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/pspearman/html/spearman.test.html), which says

> Calculation of the exact null distribution of Spearman's rank correlation statistics is exponentially hard in n. This package uses precomputed exact distribution for n <= 22 obtained using Ryser's formula applied to an appropriate monomial permanent.

This isn't even a general implementation, but a special case.  [Googling "permanent Ryser"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=permanent+ryser) doesn't come up with any implementations until we get down to [here](http://www.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/MHuber/Research/code/permanent_code/permanent_codes.html), which is MATLAB code. Googling "permanent Ryser implementation" comes up with [this CodeProject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21282/Compute-Permanent-of-a-Matrix-with-Ryser-s-Algorit), which gives fairly straightforward C code licensed under the fairly permissive [Code Project Open License](http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The permanent of `matrix(1:9, 3)` would then just be:

```
 install.packages("permute"); library(permute)
  A<-matrix(1:9, 3)

  # Error: sum( apply( allPerms(1:3), 1, function(r) prod( A[1:3, r]) )  )
```

The `allPerms` function seems to leave out the original vector, hence the need for one of Ben Bolker's corrections and I should have used `cbind` to construct the indices for the items of `A`:

```
sum( apply( rbind(1:3,allPerms(1:3)), 1,
                               function(r) prod( A[cbind(1:3, r)]) ) )
```

The fact that these values are all positive and there is no subtraction suggests a reason why this "naive" implementation of that definition is not recommended.

```
 A <- matrix(1:16,4)    
 sum( apply( rbind(1:4,allPerms(1:4)), 1, 
                       function(r) prod( A[cbind(1:4, r)]) ) )
#[1] 55456
```

Comment: based on the wikipedia page I think the right answer is `1*5*9+3*4*8+2*6*7+3*5*7+6*8*1+2*4*9`=450?

Comment: Then I guess I misunderstood the subscripting? Or Gavin's code doesn't deliver the right number of permutations of three items. You have 6 and I got 5. (And now I'm wondering why there are not 6....)

Comment: Hmm ... corrected: `sum( apply( rbind(1:3,allPerms(1:3)), 1, function(r) prod( A[cbind(1:3, r)]) )  )` gives 450. (`allPerms` doesn't include the original vector, *and* the subscripting is different.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the recursion version of "permanent" implementation

```
permanent <- function(x) {
    n <- nrow(x)
    s <- 0
    if (n > 2) {
        for (j in 1:n) {
            s <- s + x[1, j] * Recall(x[-1, -j])
        }
        return(s)
    } else {
        x[1, 1] * x[2, 2] + x[1, 2] * x[2, 1]
    }
}
```

such that

```
> A <- matrix(1:9, 3)

> permanent(A)
[1] 450
```

and

```
> A <- matrix(1:16, 4)

> permanent(A)
[1] 55456
```