# vector size specified is too large for 32*32 matrix

Tags: r, vector, permutation

I have tried the following code in R in order to calculate the permanent of matrix . But I get this error:

> Error in vector("list", gamma(n + 1)) :   vector size specified is too large.

I tried many solutions but I could not solve the problem.

```
    library(combinat)
    perm <- function(A)
    {
      stopifnot(is.matrix(A))
      n <- nrow(A)
      if(n != ncol(A)) stop("Matrix is not square.")
      if(n < 1) stop("Matrix has a dimension of size 0.")
      sum(sapply(combinat::permn(n), function(sigma) prod(sapply(1:n, function(i) A[i, sigma[i]]))))
    }
    
    #We copy our test cases from the Python example.
    
    
    testData <- list("A" = rbind(c(0.5,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.5,0,0,0.3,0,0,0,0.6,0.6,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.7,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.4,0.4),
                                 c(0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.5,0.6,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.8,0,0,0.7,0,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.5,0.5,0.7,0,0.7,0.8,0,0.9,0.6,0.7),
                                 c(0.6,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.8,0,0,0.6,0,0.6,0.6,0.8,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.9,0.6,0.8,0,1,0.6,0.7),
                                 c(0.6,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.4,0.4,0.5,0,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.7,0.5,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.9,0.6,0.8,0,0.9,0.6,0.7),
                                 c(0.6,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.6,0,0,0.3,0,0,0,0.7,0.6,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.4,0,0.4,0.6,0,0.7,0.5,0.4),
                                 c(0.7,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.8,0.8,0.8,0,0,0.6,0,0.6,0.6,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.6,0.8,0,0.9,0.6,0.7),
                                 c(0.7,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.7,0,0,0.4,0,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.6,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9,0.6,0.7,0,0.9,0.6,0.7),
                                 c(0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.7,0,0,0.6,0,0,0,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.7,0,0.6,0.7,0,0,0.6,0.6),
                                 c(0.7,0.4,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0,0,0.6,0,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.7,0,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.7,0.8),
                                 c(0.6,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.3,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.7,0,0,0.6,0,0,0,0.8,0.6,0.6,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.6,0.6,0,0,0.6,0.7),
                                 c(0.5,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.5,0,0,0.4,0,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.5,0.4,0.2,0.2,0.4,0,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.4,0.4),
                                 c(0.4,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.5,0,0,0.3,0,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.5,0.3,0.3,0.2,0.4,0,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.9,0.4,0.4),
                                 c(0.5,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.5,0.3,0,0,0.3,0,0,0,0.8,0.4,0.4,0.1,0.1,0.4,0,0.4,0.4,0.8,0.8,0.4,0.4),
                                 c(1,1,1,0.6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.5,0.7,0.7,0,0.7,0.7,0.9,0.7,0.7,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,0.7,0.8),
                                 c(1,1,1,0.6,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0.4,0.5,0,0.5,0.5,0.9,0,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.9,0.6,0,0,0.9,0.6,0.7),
                                 c(0.7,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.4,0.6,0.4,0,0.4,0.6,0,0.7,0,0,0.6,0,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.7,0,0.6,0,0,0.9,0.7,0.7),
                                 c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.3,0.7,0.7,1,0.7,0.7,0.4,0.6,0.7,1,0.7,0.9,1,1,0.7,0.7),
                                 c(1,0.4,0.4,0.5,1,0.4,0.6,1,0.5,1,0.7,0.6,1,0,0,0.4,0,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.7,0.7,0.4,0.5,0.7,0,0.7,0.8,0,1,0.8,0.7),
                                 c(1,0.3,0.4,0.4,1,0.4,0.3,1,0.4,1,0.6,0,1,0,0,0.3,0,0.4,0.1,0.8,0,0.6,0.4,0.6,0.7,0,0.7,0,0,0.9,0.7,0.7),
                                 c(0.4,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0,0.2,0,0,0.2,0,0.2,0.2,0.5,0,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.7,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.4,0.4),
                                 c(0.4,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.3,1,0.2,0,0.3,1,1,0.4,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.5,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.4,0.4),
                                 c(0.6,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.4,0.4,0.4,0,0.4,0.6,0,0.6,0,0,0.4,0,0.3,0.4,0.7,0,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.5,0,0.5,0,0,1,0.6,0.6),
                                 c(0.9,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.5,0.7,0.6,0.6,0.5,0.8,0.7,0.9,0,0,0.6,0,0.6,0.6,0.9,0.7,0.7,0.5,0.7,0.8,0,0.6,0.8,0,0,0.6,0.7),
                                 c(0.8,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.8,0.9,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.8,0,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.9,0.7,0.8),
                                 c(0.6,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.3,0.3,0.3,0,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.8,0.5,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.5,0.6),
                                 c(0.3,1,0.1,0,0,0.1,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0,0,0,0,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.5,0,0),
                                 c(0.6,0.3,0.4,0,0,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.6,0,0.6,0,0,0.4,0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.5,0,0.2,0,0,0.8,0.4,0.5),
                                 c(0.3,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.6,0,0,1,0,0,0,0.6,0.3,1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.7,1,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.5,0.5),
                                 c(0.2,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0.1,1,0.3,0.2,0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0.1,0.1,0.5,0,0.1,0.5,0.5,0,0),
                                 c(0.1,0.1,0,0,0,0.1,0,1,0.1,1,0.3,0.1,0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0.1,0.1,0.5,0,0.1,0.5,0.4,0,0),
                                 c(0.6,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.6,0,0,0.3,0,0,0,0.6,0.6,0.4,0.4,0.3,0.5,0,0.6,0.5,1,1,0.4,0.7),
                                 c(0.6,0.3,0.3,0,0,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.3,0.6,0,0.6,0,0,0.3,0,0,0.3,0.6,0,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.4,0,0.5,0.5,0,1,0.3,0.3)))
                                       
print(sapply(testData, function(x) list( Permanent = perm(x))))
```

Comment: `combinat::permn(32)` will produce a list of length `factorial(32)`, which is quite big

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating matrix permanents is a computationally hard problem (e.g.  "Computing the permanent" has its own dedicated [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent) separate from the mathematical definition of the operation ...)

The naive method you've implemented (and that is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173851/calculate-permanent-of-a-matrix-in-r)) will require computing a vector of length 32! = 2.6e35 (which will take more than 10^24 *terabytes* of memory, let alone the time taken to do all of the computations ...)

Lucky for you, since the last time this was discussed on SO (in 2014), someone has posted the `BosonSampling` package to CRAN, which uses compiled code (and an efficient algorithm!) to do the computation.  **tl;dr** `BosonSampling::rePerm(testData$A)` completes in less than 2 minutes on my laptop.

### setup

```r
## repeated definition from above, for convenience
library(BosonSampling)
library(combinat)
perm <- function(A)  {
    stopifnot(is.matrix(A))
    n <- nrow(A)
    if(n != ncol(A)) stop("Matrix is not square.")
    if(n < 1) stop("Matrix has a dimension of size 0.")
    sum(sapply(combinat::permn(n), function(sigma) prod(sapply(1:n, function(i) A[i, sigma[i]]))))
}
```

## check equivalence of naive and sophisticated solutions on small data

```r
set.seed(101)
t1 <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4, 4)
t2 <- matrix(rnorm(36), 6, 6)
stopifnot(all.equal(perm(t1), rePerm(t1)))
stopifnot(all.equal(perm(t2), rePerm(t2)))
```

## evaluate time scaling

(this takes a few minutes on my laptop)

```r
f <- function(n, type = "naive") {
    set.seed(101)
    m <- matrix(rnorm(n^2), n, n)
    t <- system.time(if (type == "naive") perm(m) else rePerm(m))
    return(t[["elapsed"]])
}
n0 <- 3; n1 <- 10; n2 <- 32
ntimes <- sapply(n0:n1, f)
ptimes <- sapply(n0:n2, f, type = "rePerm")

dd <- data.frame(n = c(n0:n1, n0:n2),
                 time = c(ntimes, ptimes),
                 type = rep(c("naive", "rePerm"), c(n1-n0+1, n2-n0+1)))
saveRDS(dd, file = "SO72004136.rds")
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
(ggplot(dd) +
 aes(n, time, colour = type) +
 geom_point() + geom_line() +
 scale_y_log10() +
 scale_x_log10() +
 expand_limits(x=32) +
 labs(y = "elapsed time (sec)") +
 geom_smooth(method = "lm",
             lty = 2,
             colour = "black",
             data = subset(dd, type == "rePerm" & n>16))
)

lm(log(time) ~ log(n),
   data = subset(dd, type == "rePerm" & n>16))
```

[image: power-law graph]

Running the naive approach for n=10 takes 190 seconds; `rePerm` for n=29 takes 18 seconds. The computational time scales roughly as `time \propto n^17` (i.e. the slope of the log-log regression is approximately 17), which is frighteningly bad ...

Once I had figured out that the problem was likely to take minutes rather than hours, I computed `rePerm(testData$A)` = 1.271369e+20 in 115 seconds. (I sincerely hope you don't have to do computations much bigger than this!)

Comment: Excellent answer! I was about to suggest using iterators which would alleviate the memory burden, but still boil down to the same computationally expensive calculation.